# Facebook Graph API - Login to website using facebook - re authentication issue

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook graph api to login via facebook to my website. I'm facing a problem here, when I Deny the access while trying with facebook. It's redirecting back to my website which is correct. After this if I used the same facebook account to signup / login to my website, it is not asking for authentication and it's redirecting back to website without loging in. This is happening since I denied first time. Is there a way I can force re authentication.

I checked someother website who is having this feature, it is working fine even if I denied first time. Not sure if they are using graph API, may be they are using javascript sdk.

I need a solution for this using graph API. Does any one have a solution for this issue.

Please do reply.

THank in Advance
Tibin Mathew

Answer (score 0):

If a user declined a permission you are asking for once, then you can not just show the same login dialog again – as you noticed, it won’t ask for those permissions again.

You need to pass an additional parameter, `auth_type=rerequest`, with your next login dialog call, if you want to ask for a permission the user previously declined again.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking#handling